# Polynomial ideals of finite codimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I was wondering the following:

Let $F$ be a field, consider the polynomial ring $R = F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, then it is a vector space over $F$. Given an ideal $I$ of $R$, what are sufficient and necessary conditions on the ideal $I$ for $R/I$ to have finite dimension over $F$?

For example: 
$F[x,y]/<x^2,y^2>$ has finite dimension, but $F[x,y]/<xy>$ does not (?)

Please do correct me if the question doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: What sort of conditions are you looking for?

Comment: I was just looking for an answer as general as possible. But primarily interested when $I$ is a finitely generated ideal - the conditions on elements that generate the ideal $I$.

Comment: I don't remember all the details, but I'm pretty sure you can compute the dimension of a quotient ring using a Gröbner basis of the ideal.

Comment: Iff $R/I$ is Artinian. (Look for zero-dimensional ideals.)